# How to convert nested Generic Record to json or nested Pojo?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro

Suppose there are two  applications , 1 producer and 1 consumer(downstream application). How can I convert nested Generic Record received from kafka topic to Pojo or json (which I can convert to Pojo using Jackson) ? I'm trying to avoid Specific Record which requires schema or autogenerated avro class at consumer level . If the producer send avro message in kafka topic , how can consumer convert the Generic record to json or Pojo and proceed ahead?

Also , how can I send Autogenerated Avro object as a Rest Api response?

Answer (score 0):

Avro is a binary format. There's mentions of using it with HTTP in the official Avro documentation, but you should stick to JSON for REST APIs.

As for Kafka, Jackson supports mapping Avro to POJO classes, but if you're using Confluent Schema Registry, then that isn't going to work, and you'll need to parse the GenericRecord yourself into your POJO class, which you can then serialize to any other format

Comment: Thankyou! One question though . How can I convert nested generic record to pojo? One way is to get field value from generic record and set the values in Pojo using setters. But if there are N nested objects ,  what can be the elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: There's no elegant way. Even if you had a SpecificRecord, you'd still need to use getter methods to traverse into the nested fields